# How to write integration/health test of a wcf service on which I have no control?

Tags: c#, wcf, integration-testing

I need to write a little more than simple test for a service. I have no control over it, but for a specific request it returns specific response that I know it should return.

Comment: Sounds like you can just consume the WCF service and issue the 'specific request' and read the 'specific response'.  Is there a particular part you're having trouble with?

Comment: Actually I am not sure about technology I should use. Can I write my own test and run it with my UT or should I create a functional test that uses WcfTestClient for that?

Comment: Just use your favorite UT tool to automate the process easily. I don't see why you couldn't.

Comment: A lot of it 'depends'.  If you have a test suite in place and you anticipate this being a 'one-off', the pragmatist in me says to quickly add an additional fixture where you just write a simple WCF client to consume and test.  Your solution should ideally fit well with whatever automated testing you already have set up.  I'm not sure what the specific best practices are on this one but they shouldn't be too hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a project in your solution named `YourProject.IntegrationTests` and place all tests of this kind in there.

You could use the same tools you use for unit testing to create your test cases (NUnit, XUnit, MSTest, etc)